# asp.net mvc wrong routing handle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-routing

What is best practices to handling wrong url routing in asp net mvc?

Example code :

```
public ActionResult EditUser(int userId)
{
  ....
}
```

1. ActionResult EditUser(int userId = 0) // default parameter and return 404
2. ActionResult EditUser(int? userId) // nullable parameter and return 404
3. ActionResult EditUser(int userId) // mvc expcetion

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I went with something very similar to this thread, it seems to catch everything I throw at it, properly displays the URL and returns correct response code.

Have a read through this answer,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577095/1538039

Comment: Thanks for link :) But this answer still doesnt solve my problem. in action EditUser(int userId) without declare id in url, mvc throw expcetion...